# Elmah and network cards

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am using Elmah in one of our production deployments and would like to secure the module to the local network only and not expose it to the public. I am aware of the remote logging option that can be turned off and also asp.net authorization, however I am interested to know if there is any support in Elmah's configuration to bind to a secondary NIC/network card which only faces the internal network ?

Comment: Can't you just edit your IIS Site Binding to have the site's IP address to be equal to your internal network address instead of being configured to allow all IP addresses or to allow external IP addresses?

Comment: I don't want the entire site to be internal. Only Elmah's *.axd landing page. Am I mis-interpreting you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built-in Elmah that will allow you to achieve this but here's what you might do: disable `elmah.axd` on your public site and configure it to write errors to some data source (a file, SQLite database or even SQL server). Then configure an intranet site which will have `elmah.axd` enabled and will point to the same data source used by your public internet site. This way you could use the intranet site to see the errors. If you have a web server farm and multiple applications you could use a centralized SQL Server database which will store the application name as an additional column so that when you navigate to the intranet elmah.axd you will have a complete overview of the errors occurring on your public production servers.